# handling Exception in django- using a base class

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

My django view goes through a list , uses regex to detect specific elements in the list and finally returns a dict of the contents. 
Both `IndexError` and `ValueError` can occur while parsing the list.

I need to handle the exceptions in this case.I tried like this

```
def parse_list(oldlist):
    try:
        newlist=create_newlist(oldlist)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug(str(e))
    else:
        mydict = make_dict(newlist)

def create_newlist(oldlist):
    mydict = {}
    for elem in oldlist:
        if re.match('somepattern',elem[0]):
            mydict['somekey']=int(elem[0].strip())
        else:
            raise ValueError(elem[0],' expects an integer')
    ...
    return mydict
```

Is using the `Exception` class in  `except Exception as e:` the correct way to handle any exception originating from the above function?

when I wrote a unit test method

```
def test_me(self):
    dl = parse_list(self.somelist)
    print 'dl=\n',dl
    self.assertTrue(len(dl),0)
```

I got the console output as

```
ERROR: test_me (myapp.tests.ParseTest)
..
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is the exception not logged by logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using the Exception class in except Exception as e: the correct way
>   to handle any exception originating from the above function?

When handling exceptions you should try to be as specific as possible. In your case, you should catch `IndexError` and `ValueError` instead of a general `Exception`:

```
try:
    ...
except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
    ...
```

Your other question:

> Why is the exception not logged by logger?

It depends on the configuration of the logger. You're printing a 'debug' message but it could be set to only log/display messages with level 'error' or higher. See [logging documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) in Python for more information.